# Logstash save/ modify configuration in environment

Tags: logstash

In my system, I use logstash, filebeat and elasticsearch
Filebeat reads the logs, required fields in the logs are filtered with logstash and saved in elasticsearch.

I have a customer requirement to switch on/off saving some fields in the log by a single config change by the customer.

My planned approach is to keep the switch variable as an environment variable in "/etc/default/logstash" location and let the customer change the variables with a file operation.

But I have found out that the logtash config is not reloaded when we change that file even if we set the "config.reload.automatic: true". So I cannot continue my planned approach.
Also letting customer edit the logstast ".conf" files is not a good approach either because the code is so complex.

Please advice on this issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it is not possible to reload the value of a variable in the environment without restarting logstash. So I have used a file read solution. The config block is as below.

```
ruby {
code => "event.set( 'variable1',IO.readlines('/etc/logstash/input.txt')[0])"
}
```

This has fixed my problem. But I would like to know is there a performance impact in executing file operation in each event